# How could it be the case that NP != EXP? Do we know of any problems in EXP that are not in NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np

I know that NP is a subset of EXP, but I cannot find any resources talking about whether NP = EXP or not.
My intuition tells me that any problem that requires exponential time to be solved with a DTM can be solved in polynomial time with some NDTM. Is that not the case? If so could someone provide me a problem that defies this intuition? Or a proof?